# ExceptionFilterAttribute for ApiController is being ignored

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception

I'm trying to replace a bad pattern in our current code, where each controller action consists of one line, such as this:

```
HandleExceptions(() => { actual.code.for.action; more.code; yada; yada; yada;});
```

I built an ExceptionFilterAttribute for our ApiControllers. It's your pretty standard ExceptionFilterAttribute, as far as I can tell from docs I've looked at:

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is SecurityException) { ... }
        else if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is InvalidOperationException) { ... }
        else { base.OnException(actionExecutedContext); }
    }
}
```

I did register the attribute globally, but really don't want it globally at this point in time:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new HandleExceptionsAttribute());
```

For testing purposes, I have set it up like this:

```
        [Route("~/throwAnException")]
        [HttpGet]
        [HandleExceptionsAttribute]
        public blarg[] ThrowSomething() {
            throw new SecurityException("you are not allowed here");
        }
```

My HandleExceptionsAttribute.OnException() is never called. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Make sure that you don't have any catch anywhere in the pipeline that handle the exceptions and swallows them.

2- You don't need to decorate your action by HandleExceptionsAttribute if you added the filter globally, so remove it and let your code generate en exception and see what happens, Looking at your code, I believe everything setup correctly and it should work.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps it didn't like that I had both the attribute and the global filtering... perhaps it was the phase of the moon. Whatever it was, it appears to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: Does it mean  that I don't should use try/catch in my code?

Comment: You should catch only the exception that you interested in, don't just catch "Exception" type and do nothing with that exception.